# C++ syntax creating an object that has no parameter

Tags: c++, syntax, instance

This question might be a little odd and I could not find anything about it on the web. This is mostly about the c++ syntax.

Suppose I have the following struct

```
struct foo
{
 void someMethod();
};
```

Now here we could create an instance of this struct and use its method as such

```
foo().someMethod();       // Works fine - Create instance on stack and called its method
foo* p = new foo(); // Works fine - p points to object on the heap
```

Now my question is - I have seen in some places the following

```
foo* p = new foo; //Not new foo(); // Its missing `()` at the end;
```

so whats the difference between declaring foo in the following two ways for an object that does not require a parameter in the contructor

```
foo(); and foo;
```

if there is no difference in the two then why cant we do

```
foo.someMethod();
```

this is just a question that I am curious about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

Comment: You can't do `foo.someMethod();` because `foo` is the name of a class, and the `.` operator requires an object (i.e. an instance of that class) on the left.   However, the `new` expression requires the name of a class, with the option of an initializer or construction arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some *subtle* differences, see [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

Comment: The meaning of `new foo()` changed between C++98 and C++03 so I am pretty wary of using it in my own code; if zero-initializing is important then I add a constructor.